# Date Parsing from mysql in Android

Tags: android, mysql

I set a column data type to **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** in my table . It successfully saved current time.

```
2016-06-28 11:00:44 // it's actual mysql data
```

But when i parse it from Using GSON android i got the date string like

```
2016-06-28T06:09:54.000Z // parsed from json
```

That means space is alter with T & Z . how i remove these two field ?

My parsing Data is Like

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String json = gson.toJson(args);

                    JSONArray test = new JSONArray(json);
                    Log.i("user registration", json);

                    //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(args);
                    //String aa = jsonArray.getString(0).toString();
                    //String aa = jsonArray.getString(0).toString();
                    // Log.i("user registration", aa);
                    String aa = test.getString(0).toString();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = test.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray valueArrays = jsonObject.getJSONArray("values");

//   // // //                         Log.e("email",newArr.getJSONObject(0).getString("email"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < valueArrays.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jo = valueArrays.getJSONObject(i);

                        String nvp = jo.getString("nameValuePairs");

                        jo = new JSONObject(nvp);

                        User user = new User();
                        String name = jo.getString("user_name");
                        user.setUserName(name);
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(mUsername)) {

                            Log.i("user_matched", "I am " + mUsername);
                            continue;

                        }
                        user.setEmail(jo.getString("email"));
                        user.setSocket_id(jo.getString("socket_id"));
                        user.setLastSeen(jo.getString("last_seen"));

                        if (jo.getString("status") == "1") {
                            user.setStatus("online");
                        } else
                            user.setStatus("offline");


                        mUserList.add(user);
                    }
```

Comment: post your code here ..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Try this `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")`. and parse your date with this simpledateformat obj `sdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replace the Extra character from Date String .

```
Date rightFormatDateFromList(String formatted_date) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    try {

        Log.e("Wrong Format", "" + formatted_date);
        formatted_date = formatted_date.replace('T', ' ');
        formatted_date = formatted_date.replace(".000Z", "");
        Log.e("Right Format", "" + formatted_date);
        return dateFormat.parse(formatted_date);

    } catch (Exception w) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

the Log **Wrong Format**: 2016-06-29T09:11:34.000Z

**Right Format**: 2016-06-29 09:11:34